# Merged questions still show up in the Unanswered list

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, unanswered-questions, merged-questions

Merged questions can't be answered, so I consider it a bug that they show up in the Unanswered list, even though it's technically true.

EDIT:
Adding the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag. The requested feature: "don't show merged questions in the Unanswered list."

Comment: Do you have an example where it is showing up in the Unanswered list? Closed questions don't show up in Unanswered, and generally a merged question should be closed. If it isn't closed, then that's an unusual scenario in itself (and one that should probably be looked at by a diamond to fix)

Comment: @Grace They don't have to be closed; if a mod sees a post they know is a duplicate sometimes they just skip closing and merge. In theory locked posts shouldn't show up in the Unanswered list either

Comment: @Grace, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53579/could-you-explain-what-marking-a-question-as-favorite-does-perhaps-in-the-faq is the question, it's at approximately #625 in the list sorted by newest.

Comment: Yep, looks like that one is not actually closed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I normally do close them first, but now that I know there's a good reason for it I'll make sure not to skip it.

Comment: Here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86333

Comment: and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987220/sql-update-statement-whats-wrong) is another.

Comment: @Pops the core issue was not fixed, [this is still happening](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284580/answered-question-with-positive-scored-answer-appearing-in-unanswered-question-l)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it so locked questions never show up in the unanswered question lists.

(for historians, locked questions *used to* allow answers but do not any more.)

Answer (score 8):

This is caused by the question not actually being closed after the merging. I tested this with [this question on Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7786/how-do-you-cope-with-nausea-in-fps), one of our only merges. At the start, it was not in the Unanswered List. I reopened it, after which it appeared on the Unanswered List. And upon closing it again, it has disappeared again.

The ideal solution is what Michael proposes in theory in the comments - locked questions should also be removed from the Unanswered Questions list.

Answer (score 5):

This is status-completed?  I find that "merged questions" do still show up in "unanswered" lists.  For example, when searching with a string such as...

search: `votes:0 views:>2000 answers:0`

*MANY* answers returned in such a query have simply been "merged" with a question that *may* contain MANY ( aka > 0 ), answers.  This "disconnect" essentially renders the search delimiter of `answers:?` - useless.

*Conclusion:*  ***Merged questions need their "Answer-Count" "hard-linked" to their new "host"***.