# Merged questions appear on unanswered tab

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merged questions still show up in the Unanswered list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66068/merged-questions-still-show-up-in-the-unanswered-list)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917151/how-can-i-implement-a-dispatch-table-using-perl-objects) still appears in the [Unanswered list](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/perl). I think since it's been merged with another question, this means it's "closed", and should not appear as unanswered.

Comment: This is reported over at [Merged questions still show up in the Unanswered list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66068/merged-questions-still-show-up-in-the-unanswered-list). As explained there, merging forces a Lock but not a Close, and the Unanswered list only checks for Closed status.