# Answered question with positive scored answer appearing in unanswered question list

Tags: bug, answers, unanswered-questions, question-lists

That's a weird title for a bug report: Answered question with positive scored answer appearing in unanswered question list.

This question: [Wallet initialization failed: basic_string::resize](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/1380/100) on Monero Stack Exchange beta was recently merged with another thread. Before the merge it had no answers and was listed under [unanswered questions](https://monero.stackexchange.com/unanswered).

Now, *after* the merge, it has one answer with a positive score (+3) and should *not* be listed there anymore. However, there seems to be a glitch and the question is still listed as unanswered.

The merge happened 3 days ago, so it is definetely no caching problem.

---

Edit, as per comments, should be: [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66068/merged-questions-still-show-up-in-the-unanswered-list (not dupe for now, since it's wrongly marked as [tag:status-completed])

Comment: I and another user are noticing occasional upvoted Q&As on the Unanswered lists at [gis.se] too. I have not looked yet to see whether a merge is in their history but I will.

Comment: I checked one of the questions mentioned above at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115028modelbuilder and found that it had a merge in its history too.  In that case the merge happened 18 months ago.

Comment: @PolyGeo FYI, I just saw [query on maximum minimum of multi-variable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2107822/602049) in the unanswered list despite having a score 6 answer. Note I've read through over 2,000 questions on this list (I'm working with a few others to help reduce the unanswered list size by checking those with answers which deserve to be upvoted), sorted by relevance at pages 121 & 151 (I'm doing it on 2 machines) but i'ts the first one I've found. As the post is from Jan. 21, 2017, I hope this problem has been fixed by now. Do you think I should write a new question?

Comment: @JohnOmielan I don't think that you should re-ask an existing question.  Instead I think you could write an answer saying that you've reproduced this here, offer a bounty and/or take a look at what you can do after 15 Mar 2020 as per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344586/our-commitment-to-responding-to-meta-and-moderators

Comment: There may be duplicates for this question - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunanswered-questions%5D+merge+is%3Aquestion - with at least one saying [meta-tag:status-completed] when it's not.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks for your feedback & suggestions. I did a search & also noticed several other related questions here. This is one reason I was unsure if I should post a new question or do something else instead. As for at least one being status-completed, if you're referring to [Merged questions still show up in the Unanswered list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66068/562482), it seems to be regarding a different issue. I've decided to wait a while to see if I notice any other such questions, especially more recent ones, & then consider what, if anything, to do then.